# Sylius plugin - how to use listeners and classes properly inside package

Tags: plugins, configuration, sylius

Good day,
I got my own package that I've installed into Sylius based on Sylius plugin-skeleton. The main class in /src folder of that plugin is called, but I need to work with other classes from /src folder. For example I got /src/Menu/RewriteMenu.php that I need to trigger method via services.yaml and I need to do this inside package - not to configure listener inside Sylius project. How can I achieve it? Thank you very much for response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have a `src/Resources/config/services.yaml` file with your services declarations there.

You then need to import the configurations from the root configuration files. For example, to import your plugin's services, you can do this:

```yaml
# config/packages/_sylius.yaml

imports:
    ...
    - { resource: "@YourPluginName/Resources/config/services.yaml" }
```

In cases like this one, you can take a look at other Sylius plugins source code to see how they achieve things. But as a rule of thumb, anything that you customize in a root level basis, can be also done in a plugin moving the non-php stuff inside the `src/Resources` folder: configs (like services, serialization, validation, etc), templates, translations, assets, etc.

Comment: Thank you very much for response! That was actually first thing that I've tried i thought it doesn't work because i need to register service.yaml as config file. If not I think It maybe would be some typo and have to try to triple check it))

Comment: Still got no luck. My plugin setup is exactly same how would I do it in reguar non package way inside sylius project, but still doesnt work I've tried to load services.yaml file with yaml loader inside dependencyInjection  extesion class, but also nothing.

Comment: Strange. I'm looking at other plugins source code and they work like that. What version of Sylius and Symfony are you using? Also, can you try renaming `services.yaml` to `services.yml`? I remember to have had a problem with Sylius not taking `.yaml` extension as valid and had to use `.yml`. It's my only guess right now.

Comment: Oh, snap... Maybe you need to import the plugin config/services file from your root `services.yaml` file? I've updated the answer

Comment: Thank you man! I figured it out probably like half and hour before you posted your answer xD Thank you so much!